# Why doesn't RadioHead ASK work on ATtiny84?

Tags: microcontroller, radio

Using the [RadioHead](https://www.airspayce.com/mikem/arduino/RadioHead/) library (ASK), I was able to get an ATtiny84 to transmit a message to an ESP8266 using a 433MHz transmitter module, ***but*** it took a little tweaking with the bit rate (the 1st param in the `RH_ASK` constructor), and they had to be at different bit rates for each micro.

**Question:** Why do I need to set the ASK bit rate to 200 bits per second on the ESP8266, but 190 on the ATtiny84? I think this question possibly also applies to the ATtiny85, as it has the same default fuse settings as the ATtiny84 (see end of question).

```
#include <RH_ASK.h>

// On the ATtiny84
RH_ASK driver(190);

// On the ESP8266
RH_ASK driver(200);
```

At first, I was unable to send a message from the ATtiny84 to the ESP8266 when both were set to 200 bits per second. After looking at the transmission signal on my scope, I noticed that the ATtiny84 transmission was a little faster than the ESP8266 transmission. So I reduced the bit rate from 200 to 190 on the ATtiny84, and saw that the message was received on the ESP8266 successfully.

When transmitting from the ESP8266, with 200 bits per second, each pulse is apparently exactly 5ms...

[image: ESP8266 at 200bps]

Note: I also tried ATmega328, and it was the same speed as the ESP8266 at 200 bps.

But, when the ATtiny84 is transmitting at 200 bps, the pulses seem to be slightly shorter than 5ms...

[image: ATtiny84 at 200bps]

If I slow the bit rate down to 190 bps on the ATtiny84, the pulses then line up nicely with the 5ms or 10ms mark, and are the same width as the ESP8266 (which allows it to successfully receive the message).

[image: ATtiny84 at 190bps]

Why is this? Is it a feature of the ATtiny84, that perhaps the clock is slightly faster? Or, is it a bug in the RadioHead library?

**Edit:** Interesting, I noticed that I had the 1MHz clock selected. So, I tried the 8MHz internal clock. If I set both the ESP8266 and the ATtiny84 to 2000 bps, the ATtiny84 is unable to receive messages. When transmitting, the wave length is even shorter than at 1MHz, which I suppose is not that surprising. Also, 200 bps on both doesn't work either, neither does my previously working 180 bps and 200 bps combination (worked at 1MHz). It seems both internal crystals are too inaccurate for RadioHead ASK (when both are set to the same bps). I'll still try the external crystal as suggested in the answers.

[image: ATtiny84 clock speed menu]

**Edit 2:** Not mentioned earlier, the ATtiny84 is powered by 5V (relevance explained in my answer).

Comment: Certain types of clock generators can be very imprecise as a result of fabrication/temperature/voltage variations. What clock source is each device using? In particular, is the attiny using its onboard RC clock, or an external crystal/oscillator/resonator?

Comment: I, also, would bet on the ATtiny84 being set to use its internal RC clock, which is not terribly accurate.

Comment: Onboard. I’ll look into using an external one.

Comment: Comments can be ephemeral and cleaned up for various reasons so I've written up my comment as a more detailed answer for future readers. Please let us know if an external xtal/oscillator fixes this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Use an external 8MHz crystal if you want to use RadioHead ASK on ATtiny84 (and have reliable results). The internal crystal is *good enough*, but not great for this purpose.

---

Aha, so the internal 8Mhz crystal is good enough for RadioHead ASK! I was missing something from the [`RH_ASK.h`](https://github.com/PaulStoffregen/RadioHead/blob/ac160f1d644ae84cc986d41d80a6a49876f06c6d/RH_ASK.h#L187) source code comments! RTFM.

This applies to both ATTiny85 and ATTiny84 (my mistake was searching `RH_ASK.h` for ATTiny84, of which there is no mention)...

```
RH_ASK driver(); // 2000 bps by default

/// Caution: the default internal clock speed on an ATTiny85 is 1MHz. You MUST set 
/// the internal clock speed to 8MHz. You can do this with Arduino IDE, tineycore 
/// and ArduinoISP by setting the board type to "ATtiny85@8MHz', setting the
/// Programmer to 'Arduino as ISP' and selecting Tools->Burn Bootloader. This 
/// does not actually burn a bootloader into the tiny, it just changes the 
/// fuses so the chip runs at 8MHz. 
/// If you run the chip at 1MHz, you will get RK_ASK speeds 1/8th of the expected.
```

It turns out that setting the fuses is what got it working; you can't just select 8MHz from the menu, you also have to click '**Burn bootloader**' to set the fuses.

[image: Use 8Mhz clock]
[image: Set fuses on ATtiny84 to use 8MHz]

Now, the default 2000 bits per second on both the ATtiny84 and ESP8266 seems to work great!

**Edit:** That said, I'll still get an external clock, since I noticed that the temperature of the chip does make a difference; ASK receive mode seems to work *much* more reliably once the chip warms up a little. It barely worked after being turned off for a while in a cold room, and when I used my hot air gun to warm the chip by a few degrees C, it instantly started receiving reliably (I suppose that could be a coincidence, but somehow I doubt it).

**Edit 2:** After searching the datasheet for '8MHz' and 'Oscillator', I found that the crystal is factory calibrated to 8.0MHz at **25°C**, and can be user-calibrated.

[image: ATtiny84 crystal calibration]

Also...

> "By default, the internal RC oscillator provides an approximate 8MHz clock. Though voltage and temperature dependent, this clock can be very accurately calibrated by the user."

**Edit 3:** Ok, so I put the test rig in the freezer. After 5 mins the micro measured close to 7°C... turned it on and instantly works for both tx and rx at 7°C (well below the 25°C oscillator factory calibration temperature). Chip temperature rising only by about 1°C, per minute, and still working fine all the while. Not quite sure why it didn't work cold this morning... maybe it was just a bug in my code.

**Edit 4:** I had an entire day of ASK not working reliably on my ATtiny84, and finally got tired of it working intermittently (reliability changed throughout the day, probably depending on the temperature of the internal crystal). So, I added an external 8MHz crystal with two 22pf caps and never looked back!

**RadioHead ASK now works flawlessly on my ATtiny84!**

[image: ATtiny84 with external crystal pg 29]
[image: ATtiny84 with external crystal pg 30]
[image: External crystal fuse setting]

Answer (score 2):

The ATtiny84's onboard RC oscillator can be very imprecise over temperature variations, as shown in this diagram taken from the [datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-7701_Automotive-Microcontrollers-ATtiny24-44-84_Datasheet.pdf):

[image]

In particular, the 8 MHz oscillator appears to deliver as much as 8.2 MHz at 25 degC room temperature; this discrepancy is about half of the 5% error you see. It's not immediately clear where the other half of the error comes from.

An external 8 MHz oscillator or crystal should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks. 8MHz crystal ordered!

Comment: Looks like a useful article: https://sites.google.com/site/wayneholder/controlling-time

Comment: @NickBolton note that you probably need two small capacitors as well, and it uses up two pins so make sure you have enough

Comment: @nanofarad Temporary workaround, based on your findings, I used a heat gun to raise the chip temperature, which lowers the clock speed.

Comment: Update: I added an external 8MHz crystal with two 22pf caps and never looked back! RadioHead ASK now works flawlessly on my ATtiny84!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think the bottom line of your ASK journey* is that, if you want to obtain reliable results from time-based processes in MCUs you cannot simply rely on the onboard oscillator. You MUST use Crytal Oscillators with adequate decoupling capacitors.

*and a very well-documented one, thanks for that :)

Comment: Thanks! You reminded me to add a TL;DR.

Comment: That would be really helpful for other readers ;)